# C++ Calculate Grade Function

Tags: c++

I am having a semantic error. I have changed my code over and over and cannot figure out what is causing my code not to output the letter grade correctly. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int getScore(int& score);
int calculateGrade(int cScore);

int main()
{
    int score;
    int cScore;

    cout << "Based on the course score, \n this program computes the course";
    cout << " grade." << endl;

    getScore(score);

    calculateGrade(cScore);

    cout << "Your grade for the course is: " << static_cast<char>(cScore);
    cout << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int getScore(int& score)
{
    cout << "Enter the course score: ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "Course score is: " << score << endl;
    return score;
}

int calculateGrade(int cScore)
{

    if (cScore >= 90)
        cScore = 65;
    if ((cScore >= 80) && (cScore < 90))
        cScore = 66;
    if ((cScore >= 70) && (cScore < 80))
        cScore = 67;
    if ((cScore >= 60) && (cScore < 70))
        cScore = 68;
    if (cScore < 60)
        cScore = 70;

    return cScore;

}
```

Am I using the static_cast wrong? I have flipped through my entire book and cannot find any answers. Is there an error with my parameters? I am not sure that I entirely understand how parameters work yet. I have read a lot on them but I feel as if I'm still not using them correctly sometimes. Please help me find the problem with my calculateGrade function.

Comment: Replace `calculateGrade(cScore);` with `cScore = calculateGrade(score);`.

Comment: Please use the debugger before asking. It would show you that `cScore` is uninitialized when you use it (your compiler should do that actually) and that `calculateGrade` does not change it.

Comment: For future reference, please at least post the error your compiler gives you.

Comment: However, even that won't quite fix it, because you are changing the value of cScore inside of calculateGrade, and then doing more if checks against it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `calculateGrade` function can return a char, which you would then turn into this:

```
if (cScore >= 90) return 'A';
```

and so on..

which you would then use:

```
std::cout << "The grade is: " << calculateGrade(score) << std::endl;
```

or alternatively

```
char grade = calculateGrade(score);

std::cout << "The grade is: " << grade << std::endl;
```

also there is no real reason to return an int from your `getScore` function as you are passing your score by reference and inputting it that way.

```
int getScore(int& score)
{
    cout << "Enter the course score: ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "Course score is: " << score << endl;
    return score;
}
```

can be changed to

```
void getScore(int& score)
{
    cout << "Enter the course score: ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "Course score is: " << score << endl;
}
```

or alternatively to:

```
int getScore()
{
    int score;
    cout << "Enter the course score: ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "Course score is: " << score << endl;
    return score;
}
```

which then in your main program you would call as:

```
int score = getScore();
```

**EDIT**:

If the assignment requires a cast to be used, the function can stay the same, but you have to call it from main in one of the two ways:

1)

```
std::cout << "The course grade is: " << static_cast<char>(calculateGrade(score)) << std::endl;
```

2)

```
int calculated_score = calculateGrade(score);
```

and then cast it in the `std::cout`.

Comment: Hmm the OP probably needs the cast for their assignment

Comment: The function can still return an int and cast it, the main problem in the OP's code is that it doesn't do one of the two things: 1) return the grade and save it into the variable or 2) pass the variable that it's being saved to as a reference. The OP is calling the function using cScore, which I would assume is where he wants to save the grade, however in that case you would need to pass 2 parameters, 1 being the actual variable where it's being saved, and the other is the actual score to compare with the thresholds.

Comment: I understand what the OP is doing wrong, I'm just stating the possible reason why the OP used that cast instead of doing the obvious (just a statement and nothing more).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing score and cScore causing the problem.
This is the edited **working code**. I only edited the code to make it work, I did not do further changes to your code to make it good.

There are more than 1 place in your code which need changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int getScore(int& score);
int calculateGrade(int score, int& cScore); //added 1 more argument

int main()
{
    int score;
    int cScore;

    cout << "Based on the course score, \n this program computes the course";
    cout << " grade." << endl;

    getScore(score);

    calculateGrade(score, cScore);

    cout << "Your grade for the course is: " << (cScore);
    cout << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int getScore(int& score)
{
    cout << "Enter the course score: ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "Course score is: " << score << endl;
    return score;
}

int calculateGrade(int score, int& cScore) //Should compare score & return cScore
{
    if (score >= 90)
        cScore = 65;
    if ((score >= 80) && (score < 90))
        cScore = 66;
    if ((score >= 70) && (score < 80))
        cScore = 67;
    if ((score >= 60) && (score < 70))
        cScore = 68;
    if (score < 60)
        cScore = 70;

    return cScore;

}
```

Since it looks like you do not want to return the value from the function but only want to pass the `cScore` by reference. You need at include `cScore` as one of the argument for your `calculateGrade()` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
calculateGrade(cScore);
```

with

```
cScore = calculateGrade( score );
```

solves the problem.

First off, `cScore` is used without being initialized. Secondly, you never store the return value of `calculateGrade` in `cScore`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
int getScore(int& score)
{
    cout << "Enter the course score: ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "Course score is: " << score << endl;
    return score;
}
```

but I bet you don't know what you're really doing. This `return statement` is really not necessary; you are saving the current score in the variable `score` which you have passed by reference using the symbol `&`, so it will be saved in the variable `score` defined in `main`. Now, you are doing this:

```
int calculateGrade(int cScore)
{
if (cScore >= 90)
    cScore = 65;
if ((cScore >= 80) && (cScore < 90))
    cScore = 66;
if ((cScore >= 70) && (cScore < 80))
    cScore = 67;
if ((cScore >= 60) && (cScore < 70))
    cScore = 68;
if (cScore < 60)
    cScore = 70;

return cScore;
}
```

but now you are not passing the argument by reference, so the `return` statement is not sufficient, because you are not storing the result to any variable! Also, you are doing multiple check on the variable you are changing. Think of it.

Here are two ways you can solve the problem.

```
int getScore();
int calculateGrade(int);

int main()
{
    int score;
    int cScore;

    cout << "Based on the course score, \n this program computes the course";
    cout << " grade." << endl;

    score = getScore();
    cScore = calculateGrade(score);


    cout << "Your grade for the course is: " << static_cast<char>(cScore);
    cout << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int getScore()
{
    int score;
    cout << "Enter the course score: ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << "Course score is: " << score << endl;
    return score;
}

int calculateGrade(int score)
{
    int cScore;
    //only one statement is true here, let's state it more nicely.
    if (cScore >= 90)
        cScore = 65;
    else if ((cScore >= 80) && (cScore < 90))
        cScore = 66;
    else if ((cScore >= 70) && (cScore < 80))
        cScore = 67;
    else if ((cScore >= 60) && (cScore < 70))
        cScore = 68;
    else
        cScore = 70;

    return cScore;

}
```

The other way would be to pass the variables by reference, which I do not suggest for this simple example.

Please note those two lines:

```
    score = getScore();
    cScore = calculateGrade(score);
```

The result of the `return` statement of those two functions is now stored in the respective variables.